# MSBuild: How to create parametrized inline-task containing multiple <Exec> tasks

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have the following simple  tasks:

```
<Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;$( [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $(_tempPublishUrl), Logs              ))&quot;  /grant      Users:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />
<Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;$( [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $(_tempPublishUrl), Logs              ))&quot;  /grant  IIS_IUSRS:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />

<Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;$( [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $(_tempPublishUrl), ReportResults     ))&quot;  /grant      Users:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />
<Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;$( [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $(_tempPublishUrl), ReportResults     ))&quot;  /grant  IIS_IUSRS:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />

<Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;$( [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $(_tempPublishUrl), ReportTemplates   ))&quot;  /grant      Users:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />
<Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;$( [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $(_tempPublishUrl), ReportTemplates   ))&quot;  /grant  IIS_IUSRS:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />
```

I want to create a re-usable task which parametrizes "_tempPublishUrl" of these exec-tasks because I want to re-use them in different parts of an msbuild script (aka eliminate code-duplication). I know I can create simple C# tasks like so:

```
<UsingTask
  TaskName="RenameDirectory"
  TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
  AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll"
>
  <ParameterGroup>
    <PathToDirToRename          ParameterType="System.String"    Required="true" />
    <PathToNewDirectoryName     ParameterType="System.String"    Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>

  <Task>
    <Reference  Include="System.Core" />
    <Using Namespace="System" />

    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
          System.IO.Directory.Move(PathToDirToRename, PathToNewDirectoryName);
      ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

But how can I employ <UsingTask> to group my <Exec> tasks so as to create a re-usable task (think functions)? I can't find an example which show-cases something like this.

Comment: What do you mean "a task which parametrizes "_tempPublishUrl""? Why not use `PropertyGroup` to define the parameter "_tempPublishUrl" directly?

Comment: I want the task to be re-usable. To that end I need to be able to call said task like a function (like the "RenameDirectory" shown above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my research has gone only way to achieve the desired effect is to extract the desired functionality into a separate .msbuild file and use the Properties="..." property of the  task when invoking the aforementioned satellite .msbuild file. This approach is not ideal since the satellite .msbuild is still exposed on global properties passed on the root .msbuild file via "/p" switches. But it's sufficiently close enough to being ideal and it's certainly better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you can combine Exec into Target with parameters and use [CallTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/calltarget-task?view=vs-2015).

Comment: I know about CallTarget but to this day I haven't found a way to pass named parameters onto CallTarget (like with "RenameDirectory" above) which I find to be a glaring weakness of this approach because it means I have to rely on what is essentially global variables of the msbuild script. Feel free to enlighten me though in case I've missed something. I'ld be more than happy to stand corrected on this one.

Comment: Just to make sure. Is this what you mean: https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2012/03/21/call-an-msbuild-target-like-a-function.aspx/ This technique seems to be relying on global variables. I don't know if there's a way to refactor it into something more function-like.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a re-usable task which parametrizes "_tempPublishUrl" of these exec-tasks because I want to re-use them in different parts of an msbuild script (aka eliminate code-duplication).

As a workaround, you can define the `_tempPublishUrl` in the `.targets`/`.props` file, like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_tempPublishUrl>SomeValue1</_tempPublishUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you can import this `.targets`/`.props` file when you re-use them in different parts of an msbuild script:

```
<Import Project="..\Path\xxxx.targets" />
```

Even you can use nuget to manage this file, so that we do not need to import this `.targets`/`.props` file manually, just add the nuget package to the different parts of an msbuild script, check the [Creating native packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-packages) for some more details.

Besides, you can also add the `<UsingTask>` in the `.targets`/`.props` file. In this case, we do not need to repeat the `<UsingTask>` code, we could re-use it after importing the `.targets`/`.props` file or install the nuget package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for tuning in. The suggested method might work but it still isn't function-ish (as originally intended). Will keep it in mind though.